# mysql corrupted installation, makes mysql uninstallabe

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, puppet

OS - Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Task - create puppet manifest, that will make apache2-zabbix page.

```
$var = ['apache2','libapache2-mod-php','php7.4-mysql','php-mysql','php','php-mbstring','php-gd','php-xml','php-bcmath','php-ldap','php-mysql']
package { $var:
  ensure    => installed,
}
wget::fetch { "download zabbix":
  source      => 'https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/4.0/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zabbix-release/zabbix-release_4.0-2+bionic_all.deb',
  destination => '/root/',
  timeout     => 0,
  verbose     => false,
}
package { "puppet-dashboard":
 provider => dpkg,
 ensure   => latest,
 source   => "/root/zabbix-release_4.0-2+bionic_all.deb"
}
$var3 = ['zabbix-server-mysql','zabbix-frontend-php']
package { $var3 :
  ensure  =>  installed,
}
mysql::db { 'zabbix':
  user     => 'myuser',
  password => 'mypass',
  host     => 'localhost',
  sql      => '/root/zabbix/create.sql.gz',
  import_cat_cmd => 'zcat',
  import_timeout => 900,
}
mysql_grant { 'myuser@localhost/*.*':
  ensure     => 'present',
  options    => ['GRANT'],
  privileges => ['ALL'],
  table      => '*.*',
  user       => 'myuser@localhost',
}
file_line { 'zabbix config':
  path    => '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf',
  line    => 'DBHost=localhost\nDBName=zabbix\nDBUser=myuser\nDBPassword=mypass',
}
```

**Problem - mysql-server,downloading on master machine incorectlly, and drops the error, that makes full manifest useless.**

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

**DOSNT WORK**

```
mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql* /tmp/wtf3
apt-get remove mysql*
apt-get purge mysql*
rm -r /etc/mysql/
apt --fix-broken install
```

Comment: Please share more details - is this even related to programming? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely just a dependency issue - Puppet is trying to install and run Zabbix before MySQL server is running.

Try changing the `package` resource to

```
$var3 = ['zabbix-server-mysql','zabbix-frontend-php']
package { $var3 :
  ensure  => installed,
  require => [
    Mysql::Db['zabbix'],
    Mysql_grant['myuser@localhost/*.*'],
  ],
}
```

There are several other missing dependencies in your manifest. Remember, Puppet doesn't order resources based on their order in a manifest, at least not reliably. [Dependencies have to be given explicitly using `require`, `before`, `notify` and `subscribe`.](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_relationships.html)